# How to display multiple columns of CardView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I wish to achieve a layout like this one that can dynamically display albums and change the number of columns according to orientation (vertical or horizontal). Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

As of now my code looks something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:elevation="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/wp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/album_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:alpha="0.85"
        android:background="@color/light"
        android:layout_above="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/avatar"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:alpha="0.85"
        android:background="@color/light"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/album_name"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="@color/dim_foreground_disabled_material_dark" />


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html). Inside `GridView` you can set `CardView` of your choice. You can set how many Cards you want to show vertical or horizontal.

Sample layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

In your Activity now you can set it's adapter

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new YourCustomAlbumAdapter(this));
```

For complete example you can see official Example http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: I tried your advice but now its displaying the following message :                  The following classes could not be found : android.v7.widget.CardView